# STATIC_ROOT and MEDIA_ROOT correct configuration

Tags: python, django, django-settings

I'm using this STATIC_ROOT and MEDIA_ROOT configurations:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'wsgi', 'static')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'wsgi', 'static', 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "")

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates"),
)
```

And I'm using this model:

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media', verbose_name="Foto")
```

But the picture uploads to this folder:

```
/project_root/wsgi/static/media/media
```

When I try to look for the picture via "Inspect element", it shows this URL:

```
/media/media/picture.jpg
```

But the correct URL is:

```
media/wsgi/static/media/media/picture.jpg
```

Can you help me on what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

**Edit**

Above info is when I'm running locally. This is the deployment data:

```
Request URL:    http://phoebe-rogergonzalez.rhcloud.com/media/media/picture.jpg
"/var/lib/openshift/bunchofnumbers/app-root/runtime/repo/media/picture.jpg" doesn't exists.
```

Also, I'm using OpenShift.

Comment: Why is that the "correct" URL? The URL is what you define it to be in MEDIA_URL; it does not and should not have any relationship to MEDIA_ROOT, which is simply where the files are stored for the webserver to serve them.

Comment: What I mean with the "correct" URL is where the picture is currently located @DanielRoseman

Comment: But the picture is located on the filesystem. What URL you serve it at has nothing to do with that. /media/ should simply be configured to serve files from /wsgi/static/media, which it is.

Comment: Should I set MEDIA_URL to /wsgi/static/media? @DanielRoseman

Comment: No, I can't imagine why you would want to do that. There is no reason to expose the details of your filesystem in your URL. What **exact** problem are you encountering?

Comment: I have a form that manages a image upload in the model that I specified above. When I try to show the picture on the template, it doesn't find the picture. My guess was that I had misconfigured some MEDIA configurations @DanielRoseman

Comment: OK, the problem is that files from MEDIA_URL are not being served. So, have you configured anything anywhere to do this?

Comment: No, this is all I've got. Is there something else to configure? I'm trying to deploy to OpenShift @DanielRoseman

Comment: Please read the [documentation on static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/deployment/). Django is not responsible for serving them in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by changing the MEDIA_URL:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/static/media/'
```

It now works flawlessly. I hope this helps someone else.